# Remove a smartinput rule for a filetype

Tags: vim

In Kana's [smartinput plugin](https://github.com/kana/vim-smartinput) I'd like to turn off backtick completion for a certain filetype (OCaml). How should I go about doing this?

Comment: it looks like you can use smartinput-rule-definition with filetype to write custom rules. Take a peak at the [documentation](https://github.com/kana/vim-smartinput/blob/master/doc/smartinput.txt) (or `:help plugin_name_here`)